# file ... failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, permissions, fopen

I am coping a site for a client, I've clones the whole site on my server and it seem to work.
now that I've copied the site over to his server and trying to make a payment (using paypal pro) i get a permission error:

```
`Warning: error_log(../PayPal.log) [function.error-log]: failed to open stream: Permission denied`
```

I've tried changing the permissions to 777 for everything and this error keep coming.

I've have looked around, in google and in here i saw that it might have something to do with php settings (`safemode` or `open_basedir`) but when i check `phpinfo()` its seems safemod is disabled and open_basedir is empty.

anyone with an idea ?

Comment: how about the permisions of the directory where you made the whole copy?

Comment: Everything is set to 777. files directories everything that relates to anything.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you use absolute path instead of relative?

Comment: Nope same thing tried absolute already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

While adding any virtual host (or even single host) you must set a DocumentRoot within Apache.
That directive tells apache where to look for the files and map the root of the website.

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/www.example.com"
```

But that directive alone doesn't give access to client to read/write that directory. You must specify the configuration for that directory, like.

```
<Directory "/var/www/vhosts/www.example.com">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all 
</Directory>
```

if your Document root (within this example) is /var/www/vhosts/www.example.com apache would need to have write/execute access to /var/www/vhosts/ and /var/www/vhosts/ would need to be configured within apache.

---

Okay.

I believe that if everything is 777 the problem is most likely related to open_basedir or/and  directive for apache.

Make sure that ../Paypal.log is accessible within apache  and open_basedir.
Also bear in mind what else is within that ../ scope and how it will impact your security.

Comment: open_basedir. is empty which by what i understand is not limiting any folder. i dont understand what you mean by directive ?

Comment: I see. ok thanks very much i will continue reading and looking about the issue as well as `documentRoot`