# Message: error_log(../PayPal.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I click on the paypal payment button, the below error is showing.

Why is this error showing?

```
A PHP Error was encountered    
Severity: Warning
Message: error_log(../PayPal.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied
Filename: Core/PayPalLoggingManager.php
Line Number: 116

[Above error repeated 5 times]

A PHP Error was encountered    
Severity: Warning
Message: file_put_contents(/var/www/html/system/paypal/lib/PayPal/Cache/../../../var/auth.cache): failed to open stream: Permission denied    
Filename: Cache/AuthorizationCache.php
Line Number: 77
Exception: Failed to write cache
( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined method Exception::getData() in /var/www/html/application/controllers/cart.php on line 1695
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  239624  {main}( )   .../index.php:0
2   0.0003  392832  require_once( '/var/www/html/system/core/CodeIgniter.php' ) .../index.php:204
3   0.0068  1541016 call_user_func_array:{/var/www/html/system/core/CodeIgniter.php:359} ( )    .../CodeIgniter.php:359
4   0.0068  1544352 Cart->paypal_payment( ) .../CodeIgniter.php:359
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [file ... failed to open stream: Permission denied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14742447/file-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied)

Comment: Make Sure the paypal.log file has read write permission

Comment: @Fairy Dancer : I also tried that but nothing happened.

Comment: Ok do one thing disable paypal log creation in your bootstrap file or ini file in paypal